# Count of the biggest bin in histogram, C#, sharp

Tags: histogram, c#

I want to make histogram of my data so, I use histogram class at `c#` using `MathNet.Numerics.Statistics`.

```
double[] array = { 2, 2, 5,56,78,97,3,3,5,23,34,67,12,45,65 };
Vector<double> data = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfArray(array);
int binAmount = 3;
Histogram _currentHistogram = new Histogram(data, binAmount);
```

How can I get the count of the biggest bin? Or just the index of the bigest bin? I try to get it by using `GetBucketOf` but to do this I need the element in this bucket :(
Is there any other way to do this? I read the documentation and Google and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

(Hi, I would use a comment for this but i just joined so today and don't yet have 50 reputation to comment!) I just had a look at - http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Statistics/Histogram.htm. That documentation page (footer says it was built using http://docu.jagregory.com/) shows a public property named Item which returns a Bucket. I'm wondering if that is the property you need to use because the automatically generated documentation states that the Item property "Gets' the n'th bucket" but isn't clear how the Item property acts as an indexer. Looking at your code i would try _currentHistogram.Item[n] first (if that doesn't work try _currentHistogram[n]) where you are iterating the Buckets in the histogram using something like -

```
var countOfBiggest = -1;
var indexOfBiggest = -1;
for (var n = 0; n < _currentHistogram.BucketCount; n++)
{
    if (_currentHistogram.Item[n].Count > countOfBiggest)
    {
        countOfBiggest = _currentHistogram.Item[n].Count;
        indexOfBiggest = n;
    }
}
```

The code above assumes that Histogram uses 0-based and not 1-based indexing.